# How to get the levels to which the treeviewer is expanded?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

lets consider below Treeviewer data,

Project
->package1
->package2
->->class1

The Viewer has been expanded to level-2. But, how to know that to what level the viewer has been expanded.

I am aware of setting the viewer to expand to a particular level by expandToLevel() method.

Is there a way to get the maximum level to which the viewer has been expanded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple way to get this information.

You could use the `getExpandedTreePaths` method and find the longest `TreePath` that is returned. But note that the JavaDoc for this says:

> Returns a list of tree paths corresponding to expanded nodes in this
>   viewer's tree, including currently hidden ones that are marked as
>   expanded but are under a collapsed ancestor.

which might not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks Greg for the reply

Comment: Greg, is there a way to maintain expanded/collapsed state in Eclipse TreeViewer, programatically?
When, i call refresh() method, the items are collapsed

Comment: Use `getExpandedTreePaths` or `getExpandedElements` before and `setExpandedTreePaths` or `setExpandedElements` afterwards.